# How to disable 'previous' and 'next' buttons in custom sliders?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom

I'm creating a bespoke horizontal slider and can't quite figure out how to disable the 'previous' button at the start of the slide and enable it as soon as the 'next' button is clicked, and disable it again if the slide container reaches the first slide?

Here's my source code:

```
  //slides container
  const cardSliderContainer = document.querySelector('.js_card-slider-container');

  // 'next' button
  const sliderNextButton = document.querySelector('.js_card-slider-next');

  // 'previous' button
  const sliderPrevButton = document.querySelector('.js_card-slider-prev');

  // slides within the container
  const cardSliderSlides = document.getElementsByClassName('js_card-slider-slide');

  const slides = Array.from(cardSliderSlides);

  slides.forEach(function(slide, index) {
    slide.setAttribute('index', index);
    const slideIndex = slide.getAttribute('index');
    if (slideIndex === 0) {
      sliderPrevButton.classList.add('disabled');
    };
  });

  sliderNextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cardSliderContainer.scrollLeft += 300;
  });

  sliderPrevButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cardSliderContainer.scrollLeft -= 300;
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class='js_card-slider-container'>

  <div class='js_card-slider-slide'>
    slide 1
  </div>

  <div class='js_card-slider-slide'>
    slide 2
  </div>

  <div class='js_card-slider-slide'>
    slide 3
  </div>

  <div class='js_card-slider-slide'>
    slide 4
  </div>

  <div class='js_card-slider-slide'>
    slide 5
  </div>


</div>

<div class='slider-buttons'>

  <button class='js_card-slider-prev'>Previous</button>
  <button class='js_card-slider-next'>Next</button>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Spectric I have now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the slides you should take action whenever the buttons are clicked. Check this sample, its a little rough but you should get the idea:

```
//initial index of the slide
var activeSlide = 0;

sliderNextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   cardSliderContainer.scrollLeft += 300;
   //Check if user has been moved to the last slide
   if (activeSlide === slides.length-1) { 
     //disable the button
     sliderNextButton.classList.add('disabled');
   } else {
     //enable both buttons
     sliderNextButton.classList.remove('disabled');
     sliderPrevButton.classList.remove('disabled');
   }
   //increase active index
   activeSlide++;
});

sliderPrevButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   cardSliderContainer.scrollLeft -= 300;
   //Check if user has been moved to the first slide
   if (activeSlide === 1) {
     //disable the button
     sliderPrevButton.classList.add('disabled');
   } else {
     //enable both buttons
     sliderNextButton.classList.remove('disabled');
     sliderPrevButton.classList.remove('disabled');
   }
   //decrease active index
   activeSlide--;
});
```